# Repeating self performSelector

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was just wandering If there is a simplier method to repeat the codes below for 20 seconds. If there is, how?

```
[self performSelector:@selector( move1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
[self performSelector:@selector( move2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
[self performSelector:@selector( move3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
[self performSelector:@selector( move1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
[self performSelector:@selector( move2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.10];
[self performSelector:@selector( move3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.12];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my opinion Just try this code below,

Take one NSInteger in your Controller's .h file, like this,

```
NSInteger intTmp;
```

then in .m file Call NSTimer method like this,

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(testMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And write selector like this

```
-(void)testMethod:(NSTimer *)pTmpTimer
{
    intTmp += 1;

    if(intTmp <= 20)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector( move1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        [self performSelector:@selector( move2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
        [self performSelector:@selector( move3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
        [self performSelector:@selector( move1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
        [self performSelector:@selector( move2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.10];
        [self performSelector:@selector( move3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.12];    
    }
    else 
    {
        [pTmpTimer invalidate];
        intTmp = 0;
    }
}
```

From above code, testMethod will call 20 times and according to your requirement your code will repeat 20 times..

Hope It works for you.

Happy coding..

Comment: 20 times? hmmmm. so how in 20 seconds?

Comment: See testMethod called in every 1 second so It will increment that intTmp 20 times and when intTmp is greater then 20, It will go in else condition and timer invalidate.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an NSTimer and within the selector being called by the timer you could invoke the appropriate move method that comes next.

You could use

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

userInfo could be used to pass some data to the selector from which the selector can take which move comes next or which move was invoked recently.

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(invokeMove:) userInfo:[NSNumber numberFromInt:1] repeat:NO];
```

Your selector could be:

```
-(void)invokeMove:(id)nextMove
{ 
    if ([nextMove isKindOfClass: [NSNumber class]])
    {
        int veryNextMove = 0;
        switch ([nextMove intValue])
        {
           case 1:
              veryNextMove = 1;
           case 2:
              veryNextMove = 2;
           case 3:
              veryNextMove = 3;
        }
        if (veryNextMove == 0)
            return;
        NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval 0.2 target:self selector:@selector(invokeMove:) userInfo:[NSNumber numberFromInt:2] repeat:NO];
        //Assuming you use ARC. 
     }        
}
```

Comment: NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval?

Answer (score 3):

Schedule a timer with interval 1 and with in the selector write your code.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(callMethods) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

selector method

```
    - (void) callMethods {
        static int i = 0;
       if(i < 19) {
           //your code here
         for(int j=0; j<2 ;j++) {
           [self performSelector:@selector( move1) withObject:nil afterDelay:(j*8)/10];
           [self performSelector:@selector( move2) withObject:nil afterDelay:((j*8)/10)+0.2];
           [self performSelector:@selector( move3) withObject:nil afterDelay:((j*8)/10)+0.4];
         }

        }
        else {
           i = 0;
           [timer invalidate];
        }
      i++;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)trickShot{
[self performSelector:@selector( move1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
[self performSelector:@selector( move2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
[self performSelector:@selector( move3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
[self performSelector:@selector( move1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
[self performSelector:@selector( move2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.10];
[self performSelector:@selector( move3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.12];
[self performSelector:@selector( trickShot) withObject:nil afterDelay:20];
}
```